# concatenate hostname with a string in AIX

Tags: shell, sendmail, aix

I have written a shell script that will trigger a mail using `sendmail` command in aix .
But I want the sender to by root@myhostname.com .

This is my script :

```
# cat mail1.sh
sendmail -t -F 'Root ' -f 'Root@`echo `hostname``.com' << test.mail
From: Root <Root@`echo `hostname`.com>
To: abc@xyz.com
Subject:Password Expiry
Hi,

Root Users's Password will expire in $1 days
Consider changing it soon.


Regards
System
```

I want sender to be for example root@'hostname'.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assign the values to shell variables. It makes interpolation cleaner.
- end "here documents" (`<<MXXX`)
- use `-i` sendmail command line option
- separate email email headers an body with empty line

Modified script:

```
HOSTNAME=`hostname`
SENDER="Root@${HOSTNAME}.com"
RECIPIENT="abc@xyz.com"

sendmail -t -i -f${SENDER} <<TEST_MAIL
From: Root <${SENDER}>
To: <${RECIPIENT}>
Subject:Password Expiry

Hi,

Root Users's Password will expire in $1 days
Consider changing it soon.


Regards
System
TEST_MAIL
```